# Is LSB's init script function "start_daemon" really used for real daemons or should I stick to start-stop-daemon?

Tags: init.d, lsb

In the context of init scripts, according to [the LSB specification](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html), "Each conforming init script shall execute the commands in the file /lib/lsb/init-function", which then defines a couple of functions to be used when using daemons. One of those functions is `start_daemon`, which obviously "runs the specified program as a daemon" while checking if the daemon is already running.

I'm in the process of daemonizing a service app of mine, and I'm looking at how other daemons are run to try to "fit in". In the process of looking how it's done elsewhere, I noticed that not a single daemon on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine uses start_daemon. They all call start-stop-daemon directly. Same goes for my Fedora 14 machine. Should I try to play nice and be the first one to use start_daemon, or is there really no point and start-stop-daemon is the way to go since everybody is already using that? Why is there no daemons using LSB's functions?

Answer (score 2):

On my system, most scripts use `start-stop-daemon`, but two, `exim4` and `incron` use `start-daemon`.

If you want to write scripts for portability and to comply with LSB, use `start_daemon`. On Ubuntu, it's implemented as a simple wrapper for `start-stop-daemon`.

If you need the argument granularity provided by `start-stop-daemon`, use it.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian (well, Ubuntu), the `lsb-base` package has readme (at `/usr/share/doc/lsb-base/README.Debian.gz`) which says:

> Note: Debian packages probably should use start-stop-daemon directly;
>   however, these functions may be useful in porting init scripts from
>   other distributions.

So, software packaged specifically for Debian usually uses `start-stop-daemon`. I can imagine that software ported from another system might use `start_daemon`, although if the other system has a similar policy, then the software wouldn't be using `start_daemon` in the first place, so it might be no easier to port it using `start_daemon` than `start-stop-daemon`. I can also imagine that software which is packaged for many systems might use `start_daemon`, to enable a portable init script. Exim might be a good example of that.

Personally, i think the readme's advice is terrible, bordering on criminal. We have a standard; if everyone adheres to it, software will be more portable, which is a good thing. Advising people not to use the standard passes on an opportunity to make the world a better place.

Comment: Only hardly anyone abides by the LSB standard, or even claims to, because it was a stupid idea to start with. Sometimes using their tools is convenient, but it is not seen as *standard* by many.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel: It's clear that LSB is not seen as standard; that's more or less what my answer says! I am afraid i do not agree that it was a stupid idea, though. Standards are good, because they reduce the effort required of software developers like me to make their code portable. The LSB is not a perfect standard, but that makes it a poor implementation of a good idea, not a stupid idea.

Comment: Not every standard is good, especially when published by a small group of companies with their own special interests which may be at odds with the rest of the Linux community. I advise people to ignore LSB freely and focus on building a good product. To make your product portable just use the most community accepted tools (ain't LSB) and leave the dist packaging to distribution maintainers.